# How to skip a specific vm instance when installing an application through helm install command?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

We are installing an open source distributed software (calling it server) on multiple aws ec2 instances through a published helm chart on k8s. We cannot edit this helm chart.
We want to install another k8s service & deployment (calling it client) whose manifest.yaml file is kept on ec2 vm A. We don't want the server software to be installed on vm A to not its max resource limits. Client can be started only after the server is up and running.

To manage the sequence of server and client start events, we manually stop ec2 instance A first and start it only after the server software is completely up & running. The core problem is that there are different configuration files for server and client softwares but since we cannot edit the helm chart we are doing it manually right now.

Is there a way we can mention in the helm values.yaml to skip ec2 instance A in its software installation and leave it for us to manually install the client software using kubectl apply -f manifest.yaml?

Thanks.

Comment: The machine that has the Helm chart isn't usually "part of the cluster".  I can run `helm install` from my development system into a shared remote developer cluster, for example, and the software doesn't actually run on my local system at all.  If you're running `helm install` from the VM A I wouldn't expect it to actually be running the installed application post-install.

Comment: You might be able to use Kubernetes resource requests, taints, or affinity rules to cause pods to not be scheduled on specific nodes, but none of that is specific to Helm.  The values are input to the templating code and don't have a fixed format; if the chart doesn't already allow configuring these things then you'd have to edit the chart to add support for it.

Comment: I see that the helm template supports nodeselector which should help me to restrict the installation of a component on specific nodes. I tried some examples but couldn't get it working. Despite setting a specific label I see that the component is getting installed on different nodes than expected. Any examples of nodeselector that I can go through?

Comment: [Assign Pods to Nodes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-pods-nodes/) in the Kubernetes documentation has an example.  Again, though, the YAML fragment there would need to be included in your template code, and there is not necessarily a standard way (or any way) to inject it via Helm values.